# The Cramér–Wold theorem for complex random vectors

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, vectors, weak-convergence

The [Cramér–Wold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem) states that $k$-dimensional real random vectors $X_n$ converge in distribution to a $k$-dimensonal real random vector $X$ if and only if $a^TX_n\xrightarrow{d}a^T X$ for all vectors $a\in\mathbb R^k$.

Now suppose that $X_n$ are complex random vectors, i.e. random vectors with values in $\mathbb C^k$. Does the same result hold for complex random vectors? Does it still suffice to check the convergence of $a^TX_n$ for all $a\in\mathbb R^k$ or do we have to check for all $a\in\mathbb C^k$?

Any help is much appreciated!